# How to publish .Net Core ASP portable version from command line?

Tags: c#, jenkins, .net-core, msbuild

I need 1 version of build for each os (win-32, win-64, Linux).
From the Visual Studio, you can choose when to publish: framework dependent and portable. But I need to do it on Jenkins.

I tried use command:

```
dotnet publish myapp.csproj --self-contained false --configuration Release --runtime ??? --output "С:\myapp"
```

but runtimes: "any", "portable" does not work.

How VS build with params framework dependent and portable?
I did not use MSBuild, dotnet build, or dotnet MSBuild because publish command adds some unique files(web.config, resources) and remove unuseful(dep*.json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find a list of all runtimes here [runtime.json](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json). Taken from [.NET Core RID (Runtime Identifier Catalog) Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

e.g.

```
dotnet publish myapp.csproj --self-contained false --configuration Release --runtime "alpine.3.7" --output "С:\myapp_alpine_3_7"

dotnet publish myapp.csproj --self-contained false --configuration Release --runtime "linuxmint.19.2-x64" --output "С:\myapp_linuxmint_19_2_x64"
```

Comment: When I used "any" from RID article - error : NETSDK1056. I want 1 build. Is it possible?

Comment: no. this is not possible. you can play with the output directory. i updated the answer.